# In app browser not closing Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, oauth, ionic3

I followed a course on some website to get token from web authentification.

I press a button, an in app browser open, i put my id and password, get redirected but my browser are not closing. I don't understand why.

Here's my code :

```
public apiMessages(): Promise<any>{
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://test.api.test.fr/v1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://test.api.test.fr/redirect");
    browserRef.addEventListener("loadstart", (event) => {
        if ((event.url).indexOf("https://test.api.test.fr/redirect") === 0) {
            browserRef.removeEventListener("exit", (event) => {});
            browserRef.close();
            var responseParameters = ((event.url).split("#")[1]).split("&");
            var parsedResponse = {};

            for (var i = 0; i < responseParameters.length; i++) {
                parsedResponse[responseParameters[i].split("=")[0]] = responseParameters[i].split("=")[1];
            }
            if (parsedResponse["access_token"] !== undefined && parsedResponse["access_token"] !== null) {
                resolve(parsedResponse);

            } else {
                reject("Problem authenticating ");
            }

        }
    });
    browserRef.addEventListener("exit", function(event) {
        reject("The sign in flow was canceled");
    });
});
}
```

I don't know why this

```
if ((event.url).indexOf("https://test.api.test.fr/redirect") === 0)
```

Isn't working...

Ok so it's not a problem from the if but the `browserRef.close()`
The function close do nothing